# Connect with page (Error 403)

Tags: python

I can't connect with page. Here is my code and error witch I have:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
import urllib

someurl = "https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=MET"
req = Request(someurl)

try:
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
except HTTPError as e:
    print('The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.')
    print('Error code: ', e.code)
except URLError as e:
    print('We failed to reach a server.')
    print('Reason: ', e.reason)
else:
    print("Everything is fine")
```

> Error code: 403

Comment: It means that access to the page is restricted ([HTTP 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `http.client`. First, you need to open a connection with the server. And, after, make a GET request. Like this:

```
import http.client



conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("genecards.org:80")
conn.request("GET", "/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=MET")

try:
    response = conn.getresponse().read().decode("UTF-8")
except HTTPError as e:
    print('The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.')
    print('Error code: ', e.code)
except URLError as e:
    print('We failed to reach a server.')
    print('Reason: ', e.reason)
else:
    print("Everything is fine")
```

Comment: This won't raise any exception because http.client does not consider 4xx as errors. Still, the response won't be a valid 200 response

Answer (score 1):

Some websites require a browser-like "User-Agent" header, other requires specific cookies. In this case, I found out by trial and error that both are required. What you need to do is:

1. Send an initial request with a browser-like user-agent. This will fail with 403, but you will also obtain a valid cookie in the response.
2. Send a second request with the same user-agent and the cookie that you got before.

In code:

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.error import URLError

# This handler will store and send cookies for us.
handler = urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)
# Browser-like user agent to make the website happy.
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = 'https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=MET'
request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)

for i in range(2):
    try:
        response = opener.open(request)
    except URLError as exc:
        print(exc)

print(response)

# Output:
# HTTP Error 403: Forbidden  (expected, first request always fails)
# <http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x...>  (correct 200 response)
```

Or, if you prefer, using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/):

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
jar = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = 'https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=MET'

for i in range(2):
    response = session.get(url, cookies=jar, headers=headers)
    print(response)

# Output:
# <Response [403]>
# <Response [200]>
```